# Mocking DBContext in EF 6 not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nsubstitute

I'm writing a unit test that mocks out the `IDbSet` properties of the DbContext; however, I seem to be getting some strange results.

Here's the code where I mock out the data:

```
var myData1 = new List<MyData1>()
{
    new MyData1() { Id = 2, Test = "test" },
    new MyData1() { Id = 3, Test = "test" },
    new MyData1() { Id = 4, Test = "test" }
}.AsQueryable();

IDbSet<MyData1> myDbSet = Substitute.For<IDbSet<MyData1>>();
myDbSet.Provider.Returns(myData1.Provider);
myDbSet.Expression.Returns(myData1.Expression);
myDbSet.ElementType.Returns(myData1.ElementType);

myDbSet.GetEnumerator().Returns(myData1.GetEnumerator());

myDbContext.MyData1.Returns(myDbSet);
. . .
myDbContext.MyData2.Returns(myDbSet2);
. . .
myDbContext.MyData3.Returns(myDbSet3);
```

When I come to interrogate the data; for example:

```
using (IMyDbContext myDbContext = _dbContextGenerator.GenerateDbContext())
{
    var myData = myDbContext.MyData1.ToList();
}
```

`_dbContextGenerator` is simply substituted to return my test DbContext, instead of the real one:

```
IDbContextGenerator dbContextGenerator = Substitute.For<IDbContextGenerator>();
dbContextGenerator.GenerateDbContext().Returns(myDbContext);
```

This seems to work; however, if I call the method twice; it doesn't.  So:

```
using (IMyDbContext myDbContext = _dbContextGenerator.GenerateDbContext())
{
    myData = myDbContext.MyData1.ToList();
}
Assert.Equal(3, myData.Count());
```

Works; however:

```
using (IMyDbContext myDbContext = _dbContextGenerator.GenerateDbContext())
{
    myData = myDbContext.MyData1.ToList();
}
using (IMyDbContext myDbContext = _dbContextGenerator.GenerateDbContext())
{
    myData = myDbContext.MyData1.ToList();
}
Assert.Equal(3, myData.Count());
```

Does not.  I get no data returned; however, if I debug the line, I can see that:

```
myDbContextMyData1.Provider
```

Contains the correct test data.

Please could someone point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: As an alternative, you can test using MDF's

Comment: Yep - that's pretty much what I'm doing as far as I can see

Comment: I'm the maintainer of the EntityFrameworkMock library, available on [GitHub](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-mock) and [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkMock/). It is based on Moq though, but if you want, you can give it a try!

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit thanks for that.  Just looking at your code, it seems to be exactly the same as mine.  I'm interested to see if it's my scenario that's different, or there's something about NSubstitute that's causing the issue.

Comment: Isn't it easier to add abstraction to class which inherits from DbContext and mock it? Then you won't need to deal with constructors which usually painful

Comment: Perhaps, and I do have tests that follow this pattern elsewhere.  However, it makes for a more realistic integration test if you can effectively "mock the data"

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/martelskiy/BS/blob/master/BookShelf.Tests/BookShelfServiceTests.cs) it might give you some insights

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can tell, that's exactly what I'm doing (obviously apart from using NSubstitute instead of Moq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
myDbSet.GetEnumerator().Returns(myData1.GetEnumerator());
```

Which will return the same enumerator instance every time it is called.

And since the enumerator is forward only, it will need to be reset. Calling it more than once without resetting will exhibit the described behavior of only being able to enumerate once because the pointer is at the end.

Use a delegate call back so that it is invoked every time the mock is called to return a new enumerator every time `GetEnumerator()` is called.

```
myDbSet.GetEnumerator().Returns(_ => myData1.GetEnumerator());
```

Now enumerating the mock multiple times should then behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks - spot on!  I'd sort of reached the conclusion that something like this was happening, but I just couldn't see it!